# How to prevent the click event using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to prevent the click event using CSS ?

I have created the form page , then i need to prevent the click event using only CSS?
    I have tried this css property, but not worked.

```
<div>Content</div>
```

```
div {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code and describe all the steps that you have done.

Comment: You can't prevent click with css, you must use javascript. The dislpay:none only hide a element, in this case, a div.

Comment: Do not change questions that much (revision 4)!

Comment: @Roy on a technicality you're right.

But you can just use hacky solutions like not making it clickable by disabling user-select and disabling pointer-events, but it's not gonna work in all cases and it's a bit hacky.

Comment: `display: none` just hides the element which makes it indeed not clickable, but I presume that's not what you want. I recommend give a class to the element(s) you want to hide and create a CSS rule for it. For example: `div.not-clickable { pointer-events: none; }` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 278, accepted):

You can try the css class:

```
.noClick {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but how to still allow hover actions on that element? For example; .noClick:hover { cursor: not-allowed; }

Comment: @iPzard check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665625/how-to-combine-cursor-not-allowed-and-pointer-events-none) out.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a JavaScript solution, but this CSS one would be better if it works. I'll have to give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

I did the following to still allow hover events:

```
element.addEventListener("focusin", function(event) {
  this.blur()
})
```

It removes focus from the element once focused. It makes sure that the element won't ever get focus.

It's very suitable for the `input` tag.

However I don't recommend it if you want a good `tab`-key-experience.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
document.body.addEventListener("selectstart", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

I'd seen it recently used in a test-practice website which was trying to prevent me from copy/pasting the site for notes taking.  It was pretty effective, took me about an hour to finally track down what was causing it.

Comment: The question asks for a CSS solution, not JavaScript