# How to combine cursor: not-allowed and pointer-events: none;

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

How can I combine CSS cursor: not-allowed and pointer-events: none; 
not-allowed seems not to appear

```css
.cursor-default { cursor: default; }
.cursor-not-allowed { cursor: not-allowed; }
.pointer-events-none { pointer-events: none; }
```

```html
<button class="cursor-default">cursor-default</button>
<button class="cursor-not-allowed">cursor-not-allowed</button>
<button class="pointer-events-none">pointer-events-none</button>
<button class="cursor-not-allowed pointer-events-none">cursor-not-allowed + pointer-events-none</button>
```

Small sample, please have a look a the forth button
cursor: not-allowed did'nt look the button, but show an looked icon.

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ccddtf8j/1/

Comment: Thanks, I don't unterstand to include jsfiddle link. Sorry

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: instead of `pointer-events: none;` you can use `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: @pedram I locked the button in runtime, by adding a class.

Comment: simply you can use, 

in css: cursor: not-allowed;

and using javascript,
e=>e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 188, accepted):

you can't do this because `pointer-events: none;` disable all mouse functions, but you can do a trick and wrap your button with a `div` then use `cursor: not-allowed;` on this.

```css
.pointer-events-none {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.wrapper {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<button class="pointer-events-none">Some Text</button>
</div>
```

[Add CSS cursor property when using "pointer-events: none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654413/add-css-cursor-property-when-using-pointer-events-none)

Comment: Work great. I use <span></span> as a wrapper.

Comment: but this requires the class to add in this case

Comment: Why doesn't work pointer-events + cursor together? I use your solution with the span tag and it work perfect, thank you.

Comment: Guys don't use span as wrapper because when you set span as a wrapper of div, it would give errors in next js.