# Angular Material Mat Menu disable matMenuTriggerFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, anchor

I have the following material menu:

```
<a mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" disabled="true">Menu</a>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Notice that I have an `<a>` tag instead of a `<button>`.

I want to disable the mat menu trigger. If I use the button tag, it works, if I use it as an ancor tag, it still opens up the menu:

[image]

Any ideas how to prevent this with `anchor` link tags?
[Stackblitz example here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-73zcnw)

Comment: disabled attribute not works for <a> tag

Comment: If you want to do with <a> tag add pointer-events: none; based on the condition

Answer (score 24, accepted):

well, the anchor tag doesn't have disabled property so you can't disable it this way.
you may change it to button and change it's style .

or you may use 
 `pointer-events: none`

to disable clicking on it. 
for example :

```
<a mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" [ngClass]="{ 'disabled' :condition }">Menu</a>
 <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
   <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
 </mat-menu>
```

and in CSS :

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:.5;
 }
```

Comment: Just a warning, this disables ALL pointer events on the element. If you have a tooltip or another click handler for something else these will also be disabled.

Comment: yes it's disabled so you don't need any tooltip or action event

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665625/how-to-combine-cursor-not-allowed-and-pointer-events-none Here's a fix for that hover/tooltip problem just in case someone needs it

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
[matMenuTriggerFor]="disabled?null:menu"
```

Answer (score 4):

In my solution, I simply disabled click event handling by subclassing MatMenuTrigger.

```
import {Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {MatMenuTrigger, MatMenuPanel} from '@angular/material/menu';

@Directive({
    selector: `[sgMenuTriggerFor]`,
    exportAs: 'sgMenuTrigger'
})
export class SgMenuTrigger extends MatMenuTrigger {
    _handleClick(event: MouseEvent): void {}

    @Input('sgMenuTriggerFor')
    get menu() { return super.menu; }
    set menu(menu: MatMenuPanel) {
        super.menu = menu;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this just with conditional binding:

```html
<button
  [matMenuTriggerFor]="isDisabled ? null : menu"
  [disabled]="isDisabled"
>
  click
</button>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  content
</mat-menu>
```