Tailwind set `group-hover` on button only when enabled
I have some buttons styled with TailwindCSS.
These buttons contains some icons / helper text (<span>) that should receive a color (different than the color used for button text) when the mouse is over the button.
I used the group class on button, and then in the inner element:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com#.js"></script>

<button class="group bg-indigo-500 hover:enabled:bg-indigo-400 disabled:cursor-not-allowed">
  <span class="group-hover:text-pink-900">helper text</span>
</button>

<button disabled class="group bg-indigo-500 hover:enabled:bg-indigo-400 disabled:cursor-not-allowed">
  <span class="group-hover:text-pink-900">helper text</span>
</button>



Notifce that the hover effect is set only when the button is enabled (by using hover:enabled).
If the button is disabled, I want to disable this hover effect on the helper text well.
I've tried group-hover:enabled:text-pink-900, but it does not work.
disabled:pointer-events-none is not an option for me, because it will break disabled:cursor-not-allowed.
Example:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/US7h6jStv9

I've managed to get the desired behaviour by combining group-* modifiers like this:
group-hover:group-enabled:...
<span class="group-hover:group-enabled:text-pink-900">★</span>



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com#.js"></script>

<button class="group bg-indigo-500 hover:enabled:bg-indigo-400 disabled:cursor-not-allowed ...">
  Button text
  <span class="group-hover:group-enabled:text-pink-900">★</span>
</button>

<button disabled class="group bg-indigo-500 hover:enabled:bg-indigo-400 disabled:cursor-not-allowed ...">
  Button text
  <span class="group-hover:group-enabled:text-pink-900">★</span>
</button>



Explanation:

group-hover:group-enabled:text-indigo-900 => produces the following css rule:

.group:hover:enabled .(classname) {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(131 24 67 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

Example:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/6BmIcNS610

Can you please check the below solution? Hope it will work for you.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com#.js"></script>

<button
  class="rounded-md bg-indigo-500 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-semibold uppercase tracking-wider text-white hover:bg-indigo-400 hover-[&>span]:text-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-300 focus:ring-offset-1 disabled:opacity-50">
  <span>Not Disabled</span>
</button>
<button
  class="rounded-md bg-indigo-500 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-semibold uppercase tracking-wider text-white hover:bg-indigo-400 hover-[&>span]:text-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-300 focus:ring-offset-1 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:hover-[&>span]:text-white"
  disabled>
  <span>Disabled</span>
</button>



Example:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/hXHNBTxnvz

Nice. I've managed to implement it with group-hover:group-enabled.

you can do this, "disabled:pointer-events-none"

disabled:pointer-events-none is not an option for me, because it will break disabled:cursor-not-allowed.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com#.js"></script>

<button class="group bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-400 disabled:pointer-events-none">
  <span class="group-hover:text-pink-900">helper text</span>
</button>

<button disabled class="group bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-400 disabled:pointer-events-none">
  <span class="group-hover:text-pink-900">helper text</span>
</button>



You gotta check if it is disabled or not this should be fix ur issue

disabled:pointer-events-none is not an option for me, because it will break disabled:cursor-not-allowed.

So you gotta write down all the disabled classes into your code or use wrapper to give pointer events none - cursor not allowed  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665625/how-to-combine-cursor-not-allowed-and-pointer-events-none

I had a similar issue recently, to solve it hide the helper text initially using invisible and pointer-events-none classes. Then make it visible and enable hover effects only when the button is hovered (group-hover:visible). This way, the hover effect is disabled when the button is disabled, this should achieve the desired behaviour:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com#.js"></script>

<div class="m-4 flex space-x-4">
  <button class="relative rounded-md bg-indigo-500 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-semibold uppercase tracking-wider text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-300 focus:ring-offset-1 hover:bg-indigo-400 group">
    Not Disabled
    <span class="absolute top-full left-0 w-full bg-pink-500 opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-300 pointer-events-none invisible group-hover:visible group-hover:opacity-100">
      Helper Text
    </span>
  </button>
  <button class="rounded-md bg-indigo-500 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-semibold uppercase tracking-wider text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-300 focus:ring-offset-1 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:cursor-not-allowed" disabled>
    Disabled
  </button>
</div>



