# Getting desired event target when listener is on the document

Tags: javascript, dom

Originally I was doing this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clickedButton = this;
}
```

However, I need to listen out for a button which is dynamically added to the DOM.  So now I am doing this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clickedButton = e.target;
    }
}
```

This works in the case of:

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

However, it doesn't work with:

```
<button><i class="icon"></i></button>
```

The reason it doesn't work is because `e.target` ends up as `I` instead of `BUTTON`, however I need to specifically target the button.  Some buttons might contain an icon, whilst others might be just text, and some could be a combination of the two.

Comment: The reason for that, is because there are a number of Ajax calls which can create buttons in various different places throughout the app.  It's a pain to remember to have to re-add the listener in all areas where a button could be added to the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check also [.closest('button')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON" || e.target.closest('button')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clickedButton = e.target;
    console.log(e.target)
  }
})
```

```html
<button><i class="icon">ss</i></button>
```

**suggestion:** better match `className` instead of element name

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realise, but `closest()` appears to include the element itself, and its parents.  So no need for the dual check, `e.target.closest('button')` is sufficient and does what I need.  Regarding your suggestion, I'm not actually targeting by element name, I just did that in the example to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1):

[You can use CSS to disable click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719980/how-to-prevent-the-click-event-using-css) on any elements nested inside a button:

#### Before:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    
    if (e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
        console.log("stop");
        e.preventDefault();
        var clickedButton = e.target;
    }
})
```

```css
.icon {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<br/>
<button><i class="icon">image here</i></button>
```

#### After:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    
    if (e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
        console.log("stop");
        e.preventDefault();
        var clickedButton = e.target;
    }
})
```

```css
.icon {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}

/* disable clicks */
button * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<br/>
<button><i class="icon">image here</i></button>
```